# Angular 1.2.26 "Error: [$injector:unpr]"

Tags: angularjs

i try to reproduce this ideal sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/L0dRPQyYR3gHho3q6wEc?p=preview

Unfortunatelly i got always the same kind of problem with dependency in modal controller

this is the main controller :

```
    inscrit.controller('InscriptionCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    'InscritServices',
    '$rootScope',
    '$modal',
    InscriptionCtrl
]);
function InscriptionCtrl ($scope, $log, InscritServices,$rootScope, $modal) {

    $rootScope.selectedFormations = ['test', 'item2', 'item3'];
    $scope.subcategory = [];
   // $rootScope.lesFormations = InscritServices.getListForm();
    $scope.newInscrit = InscritServices.initIns();


     $scope.open = function (selform) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/partials/participant/inscrit/modal.listform.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                item: function () {
                    return selform;
                }
            }
        });
    };
};
```

and this my modal controller :

```
    inscrit.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    'InscritServices',
    'item',
    ModalInstanceCtrl
]);

function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $log, InscritServices, item) {

   // $log("les formations : " + $scope.lesFormations);
    // $log("items : " + item);
    $scope.selectedFormations= item;
   // $log("avant appel ListForm");
    $scope.lesFormations=InscritServices.getListForm();
   // $log("apres appel ListForm");
    $scope.toggleCheck = function (formation) {
        $log("les formations : " + formation);
        if ($scope.selectedFormations.indexOf(formation) === -1) {
            $scope.selectedFormations.push(formation);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedFormations.splice($scope.selectedFormations.indexOf(formation), 1);
        }

        //$log.info("formation sél : " + formation.libForm);
        $log.info("formation sél : " + $scope.selectedFormations);
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
        // $rootScope.selectedFormations = $scope.selectedFormations;
        $log.info("scope - formation sél : " + $scope.selectedFormations);
        $scope.subcategory = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedFormations.length; i++) {
            $scope.subcategory.push({form: $scope.selectedFormations[i], term: "---", credit: "---", grade: "---"});
           // $log("valeur sél " + $scope.subcategory)
        }
        $scope.$close(true);
    };

    // fermeture fenêtre sans maj
    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.$close(true);
    };

};
```

i got the message about item provider when i click on my button :

"Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=itemProvider%20%3C-NaNtem"

Moreover when i want to use $log in modal controller like this :

```
    inscrit.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    'InscritServices',
    'item',
    ModalInstanceCtrl
]);

function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $log, InscritServices, item) {

    $log("this is a test")
 ...
```

i get the message :

" TypeError: object is not a function"

Who can help me?